# Column 'month' cannot be null

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

I have a code to insert data in the database, all works fine. JUst not sure why I got this error: "Column 'month' cannot be null" same goes to 'year'

```
string query = "INSERT INTO page_counter (month,year,page_count) VALUES(@month,@year,@page_count)";
        //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", MySqlDbType.Year);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@page_count", MySqlDbType.Int32);
            cmd.Parameters["@month"].Value = "MAR";
            cmd.Parameters["@year"].Value = 2014;
            cmd.Parameters["@page_count"].Value = new_count;

            //Execute command
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It should able to insert the month & year even if I manually insert there's no problem. Anyone have idea why?

Comment: are you opening connection object `connection.Open()`?

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi sorry,Ive change the question. yes, already open connection before.

Comment: Tested your code - it works fine on my machine without any edit. What version of MySQL connector do you have? i use v6.8.3

Comment: @rufanov mine is v1.0.10..So I need to update then it will solve?

Comment: Oh.. v1.0.10 has released about 10 years ago ) Yes! At least i think it will help, and by tests - this code works on newer version.

Answer (score 1):

Replace This:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", MySqlDbType.Year);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@page_count", MySqlDbType.Int32);
cmd.Parameters["@month"].Value = "MAR";
cmd.Parameters["@year"].Value = 2014;
cmd.Parameters["@page_count"].Value = new_count;
```

With This:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", "MAR");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", 2014);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@page_count",new_count);
```

Comment: for some reason, I cant use AddWithValue. Don't know why. It will return error.The error like below:

Comment: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddWithValue' and no extension method 'AddWithValue' accepting a first argument of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Ren: you might be passing some invalid arguments to `AddWithValue` try my solution it works

Comment: @Sudhakar Tillapudi maybe he using old version of MySQL connector. AddWithValue added only in v5.0.4